# KStream object when Autowired not printing value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am trying to create kstreams bean and autowire it in my service. But even if i am getting same object stream.print() is not giving any value, but print inside the same bean is working. I think I am not getting Same StreamBuilder with config.

**Configuration file**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class KafkaStreamsConfiguration {

    @Autowired private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public StreamsConfig kStreamsConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test-streams2");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.DEFAULT_KEY_TYPE, String.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.DEFAULT_VALUE_TYPE, String.class);
        return new StreamsConfig(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> kStreamJson(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        KStream<String, String> stream = builder.stream("topictest", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        //stream.print();
        return stream;
    }

}
```

**Service**

Print function here is not throwing any error also not printing any value

```
@Service
public class KStreamsService {

    @Autowired
    KStream<String, String> kStream;

    void process() {
        System.out.println("Hai");
        kStream.print();
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KStreamsApplication {

    @Autowired
    KStreamsService kStreamsService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KStreamsApplication.class, args);
    }

    private void run() {

        kStreamsService.process();

    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Note, that `print()` might buffer data (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7326). A workaround would be `foreach()` and calling `System.out.println()` in you user code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear where you are calling that `run()` method in the application.

However, it's too late to call `stream.print()` in the service since the streams have already been started by that time.

This works for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KStreamsApplication {

    @Autowired
    KStreamsService kStreamsService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KStreamsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean fb) {
        fb.setAutoStartup(false);
        return args -> {
            run();
            fb.start();
        };
    }

    private void run() {

        kStreamsService.process();

    }

}
```

and

```
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, foo
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks this worked, as you said it was starting stream before i invoke print.